# Refresh content of a div without ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a div with `id=mydiv` and inside of this div I have some content that I am grab it dynamically from database with a while.

Is there any way to use a button to refresh or reload the content of my div without using `.load()` ajax method?

```
$("#mydiv").load("index.html")
```

example:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<?php
$trtyb = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxx= '$getcat'");
while($fina = mysql_fetch_assoc($trtyb)) {
  echo $fina['name'];
  echo "<br>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: If AJAX is new to you then give it time. It's so simple with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the fresh content.  The only way you can do it is with an http request.  The only ways to make the http request are:

1) reloading the entire page.

2) using ajax - If you don't want a delay and that is why you don't want to use ajax, you could set up a javascript timer that would make periodic ajax calls and continuously update the data into a variable.  Then when the user clicks the button to refresh the data, you can just pull the data from the stored variable.

3) put all of the content in an iframe, and that would need to be refreshed (I see no benefit to using this).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can load any `div` without refresh any page and without calling ajax

**here is working example**

```
// your code $("#mydiv").load("index.html")
```

Working code  is here:

```
// $("#mydiv").load("'your url here + #your div name'")

$("#mydiv").load(url + "#mydiv")
```

Don't forget to add space in the `div` if you will not make space in `div` the program will not work anymore.