# Can we change the content of the page without using AJAX

Tags: ajax

I mainly use AJAX to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

can i do it without using AJAX

Comment: It depends on what kind of change you're talking about. But if you're already using Ajax, why do you need to do it without it?

Comment: I just want to know is there any alternatives for AJAX. can i be able to show hide the content of the pages without using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer, [Refresh content of a div without ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295299/refresh-content-of-a-div-without-ajax)

If something is to be done in server side without refresh you should be using `AJAX`. Else you can simply use javascript codes.

For show/hide content(if nothing to be done in server side), you can just simply use `javascript` codes or `jquery`.

eg.

**simple `javascript`**

```
document.getElementById('myContent').display = 'none';
document.getElementById('myContent').display = 'block';
```

**`jquery`**

```
$('#myContent').hide();
$('#myContent').show();
```

where `myContent` is the content element id

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need any new information from the server, just use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM. Add event handlers to your HTML elements to trigger your JavaScript code.

One example to get new information from the server and feed it to your JavaScript: add `<script src="...">` node to the DOM.

If you want to change images only, then change the `.src` attribute of a DOM image, or create a `new Image` from JavaScript and add it to the DOM.

If you want to draw something onto a rectangle, create a `<canvas>` element and draw to it using JavaScript.

Possibly there are many other ways.

Comment: if i want to show hide the content of the pages can it be possible to do it using javascript

Comment: @insanity: Yes, it's possible, e.g. `document.getElementById("x").style.display = "none";` or `document.getElementById("x").style.visibility = "hidden";`

Comment: thanks. it clears my confusion

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I have often done this e.g. using a tabbed menu therefore the header, footer and menu stay the same but the content changes. I did this by wrapping a class around both pieces of content, I then displayed:none; on one of the classes which causes it to hide. Then on click of your choice, using a jquery function within a javascript function, you can then toggle between the two classes which effectively gives you a content change. It works perfect for me see what you think. Here is the code:

```
function doSlide()
  {
  $('#sidepanel').toggleClass("hidesidepanel showsidepanel", 1000);
  $('#maincontent').toggleClass("show maincontent hidemaincontent", 1000);
  $('#openmenu').toggleClass("openmenuleft openmenuright", 1000);
  }
```